# Passing bean method to a composite

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I would like to know if there exist some way to pass a list getted by some webbean to a component in JSF 2.0? The webbean getList shall return a list of clients to the component. For example:

Component:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
<head>
  <title>This will not be present in rendered output</title>
</head>
<body>

<composite:interface>
  <composite:attribute name="list" required="true"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
  <h:dataTable id="clients" value="#{list}" var="client">
    <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Client"></h:outputText>
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{client.username}"></h:outputText>
    </h:column>
    ....
  </h:dataTable>
</composite:implementation>
</body>
</html>
```

The userpage shall pass the location of the webBean which returns a List object.

```
....
<components:list-client list="webBean.getList"/>
....
```

Can you give me a example please?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only two things needs to be changed.

Accessing the value should happen "as usual":

```
<components:list-client list="#{webBean.list}" />
```

The implementation needs to access attributes by `#{cc.attrs.attributeName}`:

```
<h:dataTable id="clients" value="#{cc.attrs.list}" var="client">
```

For more usage examples, check the [tag documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/composite/tld-summary.html).